# cookie issues while embedding youtube videos

Tags: cookies, youtube, embed, youtube-iframe-api, samesite

embedding some youtube videos

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/ivsFE8gK1ZQ"></iframe>
```

everything works fine but there are some issues in devtools - issues panel, like this:

`Indicate whether a cookie is intended to be set in a cross-site context by specifying its SameSite attribute`

and

`Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute`

what is the problem and what should I do ?
thanks

Comment: Given that YouTube-nocookie does some weird cookie stuff and you don't manage it, why not just ignore it?

Comment: Same errors here. @JBallin Ignoring this will not make the problem go away. In addition to being a performance issue, it will still be treated as an error on the site.

Comment: Ok so shouldn't this be reported to YouTube-nocookie then?